# How can I manually process Tfs_Analysis OLAP cube?

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to process the `Tfs_Analysis` OLAP cube using SSMS or some other tool, without using the web service provided by TFS?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not supported, as is explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400237.aspx):

> Do not use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to manually process the
>   cube. Processing the cube using that tool is not supported.

If you need to refresh the data in the warehouse more frequently, you can [change the refresh interval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Report/admin/change-a-process-control-setting).